# Explanation Hoffman's Linear Algebra Theorem 1

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The chapter of linear transformations, the first theorem that shows up states the following:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$ and let $\{a_{1}, . . . ,a_{n}\}$ be an ordered basis for $V$. Let $W$ be a vector space over the
same field $F$ and let $b_{1},...,b_{n}$ be any vectors in $W$. Then there is precisely one linear transformation $T$ from $V$ into $W$ such that

$T(a_{j})=b_{j}, \ \ j=1,...,n$

Basically, I didn't understood why defining a general transformation using a vector from $V$ like $a = x_{1}a_{1}+...+x_{n}a_{n}$, $T(a) = x_{1}b_{1}+...+x_{n}b_{n}$ and simply applying it to show that $T(a)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}b_{i}$ is sufficient to say $T$ is unique.

I would like someone could explain me the main idea behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are going to prove that the linear transformation defined as such is unique. With the purpose of doing so, suppose there are two such linear transformations satisfying the proposed relation, which we shall call $T$ and $S$. Then, for every $v = \alpha_{1}a_{1} + \alpha_{2}a_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}a_{n}\in V$, we must have that:
\begin{align*}
T(v) & = T(\alpha_{1}a_{1} + \alpha_{2}a_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}a_{n})\\\\
& = T(\alpha_{1}a_{1}) + T(\alpha_{2}a_{2}) + \ldots + T(\alpha_{n}a_{n})\\\\
& = \alpha_{1}T(a_{1}) + \alpha_{2}T(a_{2}) + \ldots + \alpha_{n}T(a_{n})\\\\
& = \alpha_{1}b_{1} + \alpha_{2}b_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}b_{n}\\\\
& = \alpha_{1}S(a_{1}) + \alpha_{2}S(a_{2}) + \ldots + \alpha_{n}S(a_{n})\\\\
& = S(\alpha_{1}a_{1}) + S(\alpha_{2}a_{2}) + \ldots + S(\alpha_{n}a_{n})\\\\
& = S(\alpha_{1}a_{1} + \alpha_{2}a_{2} + \ldots + \alpha_{n}a_{n}) = S(v)
\end{align*}
where $v$ has been considered arbitrary, whence the result follows.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This one makes it much clear, thanks. From the book I really didn't understand.

Comment: @PieroA.L.Ribeiro you are welcome! I am glad I could help.